# How can I get the original audio file from <ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f98bcf28260>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sox

I use form to upload audio files to backend, and I want to use SoX to edit the audio files before storing in S3. But I cannot get the original wav or mp3 file, Instead I get ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f98bcf28260. And the tempfile is File:0x007f98bd51eb38. Are there some methods to transfer the ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile to original audio files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the file at /tmp/RackMultipart20170923-10433-11kqyn3, its the same audio file with different file name.